# Android Studio - cannot resolve symbol 'Glide'

Tags: android-studio, gif, android-glide

I'm trying to use glide in Android Studio to deal with Gif animation from a resource stored in R.drawable but i get "cannot resolve sysmbol 'Glide'".

I've added glide to my dependencies in the builde.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

and i'm using the following code to set the image view to the gif.

```
ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.catImg);
int resourceId = R.drawable.gangrycat;
Glide.with(this.context)
     .load(resourceId)
     .into(img);
```

Comment: I've managed to fix it and TBH i feel a bit stupid.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by removing dependency from builde.gradle and sync my project, then again add glide dependency to project builde.gradle and sync again.

Comment: Command to sync Android Project: `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Answer (score 0):

I have also solved this problem by removing dependency and then again add glide dependency to project builde.gradle and sync again

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. Initially, I added the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.0'

    ...
}
```

I just downgraded the glide dependencies version to **4.12.0** and synced again
and it worked for me.

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below Dependency should be Used**

```
    /**
     * Glide :- https://github.com/bumptech/glide
     */
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.14.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]